# GettingErrorWhilerunning UpdateDatabase commane From PackagemanagerConsole in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, code-first, package-manager-console

HI I am getting error while writing Update-Database Command through Package Manager Console in .Net Core Application. I wrote Update-Database and PMC took Update-Datebase.

**PM> update-Database**

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'datebase'.
>      at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
>      at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>      at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

**Keyword not supported: 'datebase'.**

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Typo in Connection string defined in Appsettings.json. to define Connection string in .NetCore we have write below line in Appsettings.json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=BookListRazor;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  }

And I wrote wrong **strong text** so EF didntunderstood how what to do.!